# Alter number sort / number sequence

Tags: matlab, sequence, octave

I have an array / number sequence `a=[1,2,3,4,5]` and I'm trying
to create an array / number sequence that looks like `a_new` below:
The **columns** represent the orders / index the numbers should go in.

```
a_new=...
[1,2,3,4,5;
2,1,2,3,4;
3,3,1,2,3;
4,4,4,1,2;
5,5,5,5,1]
```

My thoughts where to use `circshift` but quickly found out that would not work.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5];
for n=1:5
  a_wrong(:,n)=circshift(a(:)',[0 n])(:)
end
```

produces

```
a_wrong=[
    5   4   3   2   1
    1   5   4   3   2
    2   1   5   4   3
    3   2   1   5   4
    4   3   2   1   5]
```

Any thoughts? It doesn't need to use `circshift` if that won't work.

PS: I'm using Octave 4.2 which is similar to Matlab

Comment: can you explain your matrix? why is the first column a different direction than the others? Are you 100% sure this is what you want? `circshift` wont work because of this, the first column is a special case

Comment: @AnderBiguri the columns represent the orders / index the numbers should go in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably quite a few different ways to generate this matrix. Here's one using the functions [`repmat`](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Special-Utility-Matrices.html#index-repmat), [`toeplitz`](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Famous-Matrices.html#index-toeplitz), [`tril`](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Rearranging-Matrices.html#index-tril), and [`triu`](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Rearranging-Matrices.html#index-triu):

```
>> a_new = tril(repmat(a.', 1, numel(a)), -1)+triu(toeplitz(a))

a_new =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     1     2     3     4
     3     3     1     2     3
     4     4     4     1     2
     5     5     5     5     1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a built-in function, but this should work;

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5];
a_out = ones(length(a), length(a))
for n=1:5
    a_out(n,:) = [n*ones(n-1),a(n:end)]
end
```

I do not have Octave or MATLAB installed on my computer, so I cannot test it. This may have a silly error, forgive me for that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`spdiags`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) to generate the matrix:

```
n = numel(a);    
a_new = spdiags([repmat(flip(a).',1,n); repmat(a,n-1,1)],(1-n):0);
```